# ng-reflect vs. 'real' attribute value on nativeElement during testing

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I try to test a custom input element in angular4/5 with karma/jasmine nut I can't figure out if I miss a thing.

Can anybody please point me in the right direction?

So I have a custom input component like:

```
<div>
  <input class="input-class" [type]="inputType" [required]="required" [disabled]="disabled"          [(ngModel)]="value" (input)="handleChange()" />
  <label>...</label>
</div>
```

Now I like to test the disabled attribute on the nativeElement for example:

```
it('can be disabled', () => {
formControl.disable();
    let inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input-element'))
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // works:
    expect(inputElement.attributes.getNamedItem('ng-reflect-is-disabled')).toBeTruthy();
    // works not:
    expect(inputElement.disabled).toBeTruthy();   
    // also doesn't work:
    expect(inputElement.attributes.getNamedItem('disabled')).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Why can I see the change on the ng-reflect attribute but not on the original? Do I miss a call to trigger a lifecyle event? O have I to use protractor test?

Answer (score 4):

So I figured it out.

```
fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
  expect(inputElement().attributes.getNamedItem('disabled')).toBeTruthy();
  expect(inputElement().disabled).toBeTruthy();
});
```

do trick.

Comment: I would give a hundred upvotes if I could. This solved my problem where I was stuck for hours.

Comment: Where does inputElement() come from?

Comment: Does this really solve the problem, or is the test just not asserting because of the promise?